# how to detect whether a facebook API token is v2 or v1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

if I have a FB API token, how can I tell if it's a v2 or a v1?

I ask because my backend is not yet ready to deal with v2 tokens (scoped fbids and all that mess) and I'd like to reject them as invalid, rather than have them wreak havoc on my data.

the question is general-purpose FB API question, but my implementation is python/django if anyone cares.

UPDATE: the backend is a REST app, the tokens come from client apps on mobile (ios/android)

Comment: How would you get a v2.0 access token if you are not using v2.0?

Comment: @WizKid I'm seeing app-scoped FBIDs in my system which are causing collisions on unique keys because I'm treating both FBID and username as unique... because I'm suddenly seeing two FBIDs with the same username, things are blowing up

Comment: But you will only get app-scoped FBIDs if you are using a v2.0 login somewhere

Comment: @WizKid I know, but I don't control all the points of login (they are in the mobile apps)... I need a sanity check that the token is actually usable

Comment: What do you mean? Are you stealing access tokens from apps that are not yours?

Comment: @wizkid lol no, I handle the backend and other developers do the mobile apps and I need a sanity checkpoint that they're doing the right thing and forcing v1 login